# Do I need Anaconda installed if I already have PyCharm? If so will they work well together?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

So I have PyCharm install on my Mac. I just started a course that talks about using Anaconda but nothing about PyCharm. I'm still a beginner learning the language but I feel I need to start writing code while still studying. Do I need to install Anaconda even if I have PyCharm? And if so will they both work well together?

Comment: Yes, they will work together. You don't really *need* either one, but if your course recommends Anaconda then you should probably use it, no? Personally, I think you should ditch Pycharm if you are a beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyCharm is a development environment and Anaconda is an all-in-one way to install a nice stack of Python tools and packages (numpy, pandas, etc. - lots of data science tools but many general purpose tools as well). They work together fine - you just need to set up a run configuration that points to the Anaconda installation.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Anaconda was using it for a machine learning learning class. We used jupyter notebook to do all our learning and projects. From what I've noticed, people mostly use Anaconda for data science and machine learning related applications. But since you are just starting to learn python, I recommend just sticking with PyCharm.

Comment: They aren't mutually exclusive.